# I am trying to implement timer using c in ubuntu, but receiving errors of declaration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, timer

please help me, i want to implement timer using c in ubunto. i have  the written the code but it is giving two errors. I am compiling it using -lrt option of gcc.
Errors i am getting is:
timer1.c: In function ‘main’:
timer1.c:18:52: error: ‘SIG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
timer1.c:18:52: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
timer1.c:21:23: error: ‘handler’ undeclared (first use in this function)

My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

timer_t timerid;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


           struct sigevent sev;
           struct itimerspec its;
           long long freq_nanosecs;
           sigset_t mask;
           struct sigaction sa;
    printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIG);

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);


    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;

 printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);
//    timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid);
    /* Start the timer */

    its.it_value.tv_sec = 1000;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec =0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

    timer_settime(timerid,0, &its, NULL);
    sleep(10);


}


 static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
   if(si->si_value.sival_ptr != &timerid)
    {
        printf("Stray signal\n");
        } 
  else 
    {
        printf("Caught signal from timer\n");
        }


}
```

Comment: you need to at least list the definition for your handler function before main(), otherwise the compiler doesn't know that it exists yet.

where does SIG come from? what is it supposed to represent? did you forget to include some header file?

Comment: thanks mike.I have put the handler() before main(). One error is gone . the remaining error is : ‘SIG’ undeclared .

Comment: Notice that calling a `printf` from inside a signal handler is bad practice (undefined behavior). Read `signal(7)` man page about async-signal-safe functions.

Comment: @mike : SIG is the signal number (variable of sigevent structure defined in signal.h)

Comment: make sure the token 'SIG' actually exists in that file. i google'd for that file and didn't find any declaration of macro or variable SIG in it...

Comment: Thanks @mike i forgot to code the macro #define SIG SIGRTMIN. After doing this i have an error
' In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status'

Answer (score 1):

`SIG` is undeclared because you never declare it, and we can't tell you how to fix it since we don't know what it's supposed to be. `handler` is undeclared because you forgot the forward declaration. Put a copy of the function signature followed by a semicolon before the function where it's used.

```
static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...
```

Comment: i have declared SIG now...... now i am recieving the error :

 In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Sounds like you goofed the forward declaration.

Comment: no i forgot code the macro as SIGRTMIN is defined in some other header file